# php - ajax update button not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm making a address book in php / sql / ajax currently I have this :

[image: I'm loading the selected contact's informations] with ajax like this :

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: "select.php",
                    dataType: "html",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        "id": id
                    },
                    success: function(Result) {
                        $('#result').html(Result);
                    }
                });
```

but my problem is to edit the contact inforamtions.
in the select.php which get the contact id to select from the db and display it, I added  many textbox allowing us to edit the datas but when i press the button submit it doesn't do anything.

`

```
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $prenom=$_POST["prenom"];
    $nom=$_POST["nom"];
    $tel=$_POST["tel"];
    $ville=$_POST["ville"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    //$q= "UPDATE `flexyperso`.`ca11` SET `prenom` = '".$name."', `nom` = '".$nom."', `tel` = '".$tel."', `ville` = '".$ville."', `email` = '".$email."' WHERE contact_id = '2'";
    echo "button pressed ";
    mysql_query($q);
}
```

`

Does anyone know why the button detection don't work ?

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: You're only sending `id`, so you never enter the `if` statement `if(isset($_POST['update']))` You will need to send the other data too.

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: because `$_POST['update']` does not exist in the request... even if it did the update would not happen you commented it out

Answer (score 0):

You're only sending `id`, so you never enter the `if` statement `if(isset($_POST['update']))` You will need to send the other data too.

```
data: {
    "update" : update,
    "id" : id,
     // other data here - nom, tel, etc.
  },
```

Comment: Oh I can't check directly in the select.php where the button is located?

Comment: Not as long as you're using AJAX to send the data. If you're using AJAX you have to define each bit of data you want to send or you can serialize the form. https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: But all the form is located in the select.php which I loaded with ajax. Does it mean I have to put this form inside my main page?

Comment: Ideally your form is in an HTML file, your JavaScript is in its own file and your PHP is in another file. You would include your JavaScript in your HTML file and then "call out" to the PHP with AJAX.